# Moderator rejected suggested edit on "flaggable" post

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I was reading a question, and in a comment line in the code I came across and offensive (profane) word. I decided to remove the word in an edit, instead of flagging the post. Two reviewers approved my edit, but then a moderator rejected it. Is there a reason it was rejected by a moderator? I am really confused as to why it was rejected. Here's the edit:https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3110951

Does anyone know why? Was it rejected because the word is hard to find?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't be suggesting edits on bad posts in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I have flagged the post? Most of the post was fine, so I thought I should just edit the word out.

Comment: I couldn't find the profanity even when I was looking for it in that @#!*#$ wall of code (just a pointless observation).

Comment: @TimMedora, it's at the bottom right of the second code block...sorry it's kind of obscure. I thought that if I put where it was in the reason for editing, the reviewers would see it, but I guess they didn't or didn't look, or had another reason.

Comment: @davidsbro - My comment was slightly tongue-in-cheek. I did eventually find it after I noticed your note on the edit. In seriousness, I don't think it's a great question because it's essentially saying, "here's all my code...where do I add ABC?" That doesn't mean I disagree with your edit, but I would probably have tried to clean the question up more.

Comment: @TimMedora If you click the "markdown" button on suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3110951, you'll only see the changed lines. It makes it very easy to find the differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the reject reason:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I'll emphasize some key words:

> This edit is **too minor**; suggested edits should **be substantive improvements** addressing **multiple issues** in the post.

The edit didn't address other issues with the post. The code needs some formatting help. See the stray bracket outside the block? There is a ["Thanks" line that should have been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). You could have even gone further and turned that link to YouTube from a dumped link into an inline link.

Now, regarding your reason to edit: Stack Overflow is an adult-oriented site and the general policy is to not do anything if it's not being used in a rude way. Now, I don't like profanity, but unless someone is directing it at me, I will tend to ignore it until it gets out of hand.

Comment: So should I go back and edit those things along with the word? But I also thought users were supposed to remove profanity if they could, and flag if it got bad.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Here's one example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177629/should-i-edit-a-post-only-to-replace-profanity-words-which-are-used-in-non-offe

Comment: Correct, however, it isn't harming anyone by leaving it. If you want to remove the profanity, feel free to try again. Just be sure to fix other issues.

Comment: @davidsbro Part of the responsibility of editing other people's posts is to fix it properly - if you can't or won't then don't bother. You had to really look to find it (it was scrolled out of view), and it wasn't intended to be offensive (obviously a copy paste from actual code base) so it's not a huge deal.

Comment: @slugster, thanks for editing the post. I know one's supposed to fix the post as much as possible, and I think I didn't because I just wanted to remove the word. You're right though, I should've fixed the formatting and everything else I saw. But I am still a little confused as to why a moderator wouldn't remove the word...there's no point in leaving it in.

Comment: @davidsbro It will get removed - whenever someone makes a substantial edit. The moderator wasn't voting against removing the word; the moderator was voting against a minor edit. The same moderator would probably be fine with removing the word if it's in a more substantial improvement to the post.